# Pascal : inverting a string with recursion

Tags: recursion, pascal

I'm trying to learn recursion in pascal, and i have this code to invert a string with recursion :

```
Function Invert (ch:string) : string;

    begin
     if ch='' then
     Invert:=''
     else

     Invert:=copy(ch,length(ch),1)+Invert(copy(ch,1,length(ch)-1));
    end;
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here step by step.
Thank you.

Comment: I hope this is an exercise, because it is an extremely bad idea to use recursion over strings. The limited stack size means, it will fail for longer strings. `copy`, `+` will need a huge amount of heap allocations. Last but not least, updating the reference counts on strings in freepascal function calls is very inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is empty, its inversion is just the empty string; otherwise, the inversion is the last character followed by the inversion of (the string minus its last character).

Fortunately, you have a function that can invert a string: `Invert`.

Comment: It's the Inversion part that i don't understand, how do we invert with recursion

Comment: @Ashref - Crop the last character and put it aside. Do it again to the remaining part. Do it again to the remaining part. Do it again to the remaining part.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz And when we stop?

Comment: @Ashref - When there's no remaining part, "If the string is empty".

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: You realize that what you described doesn't *produce* anything, right?

Comment: @Scott - No, I didn't realize any such thing.

Comment: What I did realize is, it is my comments rather than your answer that explained the recursion to the OP.